# Mongodb performance of $in with single array element vs. $eq

Tags: mongodb

In our code, for convenience, we use queries like

```
db.collection.find({ "field": { $in: array } })
```

even if `array` contains only a single element. We could have rewritten it in this case to simply be

```
db.collection.find({ "field": "element" })
```

We thought that these queries would behave the same, however we noticed that with complex queries, that contain `$or` operators and multiple fields, while `explain()` shows the same query plan for both cases, actually running the queries returns quickly for the simple case, while using `$in` takes forever because maybe it's using different index scans.

Why wouldn't the mongodb query compiler turn `$in` with a single element into the same as `$eq`? And why would `explain()` still show that they're using the same index scans and fetches, while actually running the queries obviously uses different plans?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you using, and what queries are you comparing? In your current description you mention "complex `$or` operators and multiple fields", which seems a separate question from `$in`  with a single array element versus the equivalent equality criteria. It would also be helpful if you can link to a gist/pastebin/... with the output of `explain(true)` for the two queries you are comparing.

Answer (score 19):

It's the same

use

```
.explain()
```

to see the final query

```
db.collection.find({ "field": { $in: array } }).explain()
db.collection.find({ "field": "element" }).explain()
```

the `$in` translated to `$eq` if array contains only 1 element